# How would I test this ng-click method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have the following method bound to an `ng-click` on my `scope` by using the `controllerAs` syntax:

```
vm.setCap = function(cap) {
  playersService.setCap(
    {playerId: playerId},
    {limit: cap}
  ).$promise.then(function() {
    alert('success');
  }, function() {
    alert('error');
  });
};
```

All I want to test is that when I call `vm.setCap`, `playersService.setCap` is called once with the correct parameters.

This is what I have tried, but I keep getting the error further down:

```
it('should call a setCap method', function() {
  spyOn(playersService, 'setCap');
  expect(PlayersController.setCap).toBeDefined();
  PlayersController.setCap(1000);
  expect(playersService.setCap).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'playersService.setCap({playerId:playerId},{limit:cap}).$promise')
```

Comment: Post all your test code please.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller attach `playersService` to the `vm` and then do this instead:

`spyOn(PlayersController.playerService, 'setCap');`

So your controller will look like this:

```
vm.playersService = playersService;
vm.setCap = function (cap) {
    playersService.setCap({
        playerId : playerId
    }, {
        limit : cap
    }).$promise.then(function () {
        alert('success');
    }, function () {
        alert('error');
    });
};
```

The test does not know about your playerService variable as it is local to your controller, by attaching it to the vm you can run your test.